# Does Xamarin cross platform development support ios on Windows?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin-studio

I have Windows 7, the latest Xamarin Studio and all of its components and I want to build a cross-platform mobile app. Does the cross-platform developing work and will it build also an iOS app, Android app and so?
I do not understand it completely. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios for developing iOS Apps with Xamarin

1. Use Visual Studio on Windows (requires Xamarin Business license or better) with a Mac Build Host
2. Use Xamarin Studio on a Mac (any Xamarin license)

In either scenario you must have a Mac somewhere in the build chain.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Microsoft purchased Xamarin and Xamarin now comes as part of Visual Studio and is accessible with any Visual Studio license. (Old Xamarin Liscenses still work if you have one).

To Answer the original question.
You can write code for iOS on Windows however to compile the code you need access to a mac with XCode. Apple will not allow any program not compiled on a mac to run natively on iOS. To get around this constraint Visual Studio and\or Xamarin Studio automates the Mac and Xcode to compile the code you write.

Android does not have this restriction and can be compiled on either Windows or iOS using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio. Android is dependent on the Xamarin SDK
 which can be install in either environment.

Android will build on Windows just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using ***Mac build Host*** you can do but you'll need the networked mac for developing and debugging too.

or else you can use ***[Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/)*** using which you can ***debug,develop and deploy*** the app completely in windows ***without the help of any Apple system*** but to sign and release the app to appstore you will need Apple System though